# Python mulithreading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

In case of Lock() why we can not use recursive function.
My understanding on this is: suppose we have called l.acquire() and we know lock object can be acquired by only one thread at a time even owner thread also can not call multiple times.
Now suppose I have wrote some recursive functions and inside function it is having acquire and release of respective owner thread so when 2nd time i am calling it should work because we have wrote l.release (here it may ask second thread to hold and let complete first thread job)but lock should work for recursive.

Abstract : in lock why we can not use recursive functions although we having acquire() and release().

Comment: Why do you think "we can not use recursive function"?  Did someone tell you that?  Did you read it somewhere?  Did you try it and find that it didn't work somehow?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @DennisSparrow If we can use recursive function in lock method then why we are going for Rlock().I have checked with lock() and found that program is getting halt(need to use cntrl+b to stop).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I believe you are asking about the interaction between thread synchronization and recursive calls.

In pseudocode, this should work:

```
lock object
unlock object
recursive call
```

The object is not locked when the recursive call happens, so the function should be able to lock it again.

With a Lock object, this should not work:

```
lock object
recursive call
unlock object
```

When the function is called recursively, it finds that it cannot lock the object because it has already been locked by the calling layer of the same function.  The Lock object is not designed to detect that it was previously locked by the same thread.  It doesn't know anything about recursion, so the result is the same as if you tried to acquire the Lock twice in succession:  the second try fails because the lock has already been acquired.  I am guessing this is the situation you encountered that you described as "program is getting halt."

The Rlock class is designed to solve this problem.  Once a Lock is locked, it can't be locked again, so with a recursive call, you get a thread blocking itself, as I just described.  In contrast, an Rlock can be locked multiple times by the same thread, and it keeps track of how many times it has been locked and has to be unlocked the same number of times to be fully released.  So this works for recursive calls:  each layer of calling by the same thread can lock the Rlock without being blocked by previous uses, and if each layer unlocks it, it will be fully released after the last recursive call, and not before.